# Card Game Deck Printing

Tags: class, python-3.x, simulation

I am following a pretty good python book and it teaches you how to create a simulation for some card games. As you can see below I have created a class "Card", for indexes all possible combinations of cards in a deck. Then I created a class "Deck", which makes the deck from the combinations of cards in "Card". My question is this, I'm trying to print the deck, and everytime it gives me "King of Spades". If I change the ranges in the loops to create the deck, it will give me something else. Am I doing something wrong with the ranges, or something wrong with the class functions perhaps? If anything, I hope the code is interesting to some of you. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
class Card:
def __init__(self, suit = 0, rank = 2):
    Card.suit = suit
    Card.rank = rank
#Two class attributes that are helpful in determining suit/rank
ranklist = ['narf', 'Ace', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five' \
'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
suitlist = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
def __repr__(self):
    return (self.ranklist[self.rank] + " of " + self.suitlist[self.suit])

class Deck:
def __init__(self):
    self.cards = []
    for suit in range(4):
        for rank in range(1,14):
            self.cards.append(Card(suit,rank))
def printDeck(self):
    for card in self.cards:
        print(card)
def __repr__(self):
    s = ""
    for i in range(len(self.cards)):
        s = s + " " + str(self.cards[i]) + "\n"
        return s
deck = Deck()
print(deck)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure the answer lies with the line:

`self.cards.append(Card(suit,rank))`

It is no coincidence that the King of Spades is the last card that is added to the deck, I think its a problem with objects being passed reference. Ill update this with a proper answer when I can but this might give you a better idea whats going wrong

EDIT: this should work

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self):
        Card.suit = 0
        Card.rank = 2
    #Two class attributes that are helpful in determining suit/rank
    ranklist = ['narf', 'Ace', 'One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five' \
    'Six', 'Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine', 'Ten', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
    suitlist = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
    def __repr__(self):
        return (self.ranklist[self.rank] + " of " + self.suitlist[self.suit])

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        for suit in range(4):
            for rank in range(1,14):
                x = Card()
                x.suit = suit
                x.rank = rank
                self.cards.append(x)
    def printDeck(self):
        for card in self.cards:
            print(card)
    def __repr__(self):
        s = ""
        for i in range(len(self.cards)):
            s = s + " " + str(self.cards[i]) + "\n"
        return s
deck = Deck()
deck.printDeck()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with how you are initializing the `Card` class

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit = 0, rank = 2):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
```

The `self` parameter is required to initialize the class.

Additionally there's an issue with the implementation of `__repr__` you are using in the `Deck` class I don't think it's doing what you want. When you call `print(deck)` it looks for the `__str__` method for `deck` then if it doesn't find it it will then look for `__repr__`. The problem in your code is that the return value just boots you out of the loop prematurely.

```
def __repr__(self):
    s = ""
    for i in range(len(self.cards)):
        s = s + " " + str(self.cards[i]) + "\n"
        return s #oops leaves your loop on the first iteration
```

Instead do this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    s = ""
    for i in range(len(self.cards)):
        s = s + " " + str(self.cards[i]) + "\n"

    return s #now it gets the whole string in s before returning
```

But even better is to remove this `range(len())` because it's completely unnecessary and harder to read:

```
def __repr__(self):
    s = ""
    for card in self.cards:
        s = s + " " + str(card) + "\n"

    return s
```

Also you are using `__repr__` in a place where you really should be using `__str__`, `__repr__` is meant to be able to completely recreate the class using the output. Basically `__repr__` is meant to be valid python code which could instantiate and recreate the class. If you are wanting an informal string representation of a class like you are doing here then using `__str__` is the pythonic convention.

Comment: I'm sort of new to programming, can you explain what you mean? Do you mean at the very beginning of the code when I initialize the Card class, or within the __init__ deck function? Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @srhoades28, what exactly doesn't make sense here?

Comment: So I've been adding more functionality to my code and ran into another problem. I'm trying to create code to remove a card from the deck, but despite the card being in the deck, the program returns None. Is this because it isn't finding Deep equality in the lists? Here is the additional remove function:                               'def removeCard(self, card):
    if card in self.cards:
 self.cards.remove(card)
 return True
    else:
 pass'

Comment: @srhoades28, it's really hard to know what's going on without seeing the code you wrote.